# MongoDB filter data Aggregation Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

Hello everyone I would like to filter on the brand and also on rating
Here is the data I want to filter

```
[
    {
        "name": "iPhone 6",
        "category": "High-Tech",
        "productId": "LhKiRGr6",
        "details": {
            "rating": "5",
            "stocks": "20",
            "price": "800000",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tags1": "Apple",
                    "tags2": null,
                    "tags3": null
                }
            ],
            "brand": "Apple",
            "description": "Iphone X",
            "picture": [
                {
                    "picture1": "photo1",
                    "picture2": null,
                    "picture3": null,
                    "picture4": null,
                    "picture5": null
                }
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "thumbnail1": "thumbails 1",
                    "thumbnail2": null,
                    "thumbnail3": null,
                    "thumbnail4": null,
                    "thumbnail5": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "iPhone X",
        "category": "High-Tech",
        "productId": "dgCvi8NJ",
        "details": {
            "rating": "5",
            "stocks": "20",
            "price": "800000",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tags1": "Apple",
                    "tags2": null,
                    "tags3": null
                }
            ],
            "brand": "Apple",
            "description": "Iphone X",
            "picture": [
                {
                    "picture1": "photo1",
                    "picture2": null,
                    "picture3": null,
                    "picture4": null,
                    "picture5": null
                }
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "thumbnail1": "thumbails 1",
                    "thumbnail2": null,
                    "thumbnail3": null,
                    "thumbnail4": null,
                    "thumbnail5": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "iPhone X",
        "category": "High-Tech",
        "productId": "4LvrygsV",
        "details": {
            "rating": "4",
            "stocks": "20",
            "price": "800000",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tags1": "Apple",
                    "tags2": null,
                    "tags3": null
                }
            ],
            "brand": "Apple",
            "description": "Iphone X",
            "picture": [
                {
                    "picture1": "photo1",
                    "picture2": null,
                    "picture3": null,
                    "picture4": null,
                    "picture5": null
                }
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "thumbnail1": "thumbails 1",
                    "thumbnail2": null,
                    "thumbnail3": null,
                    "thumbnail4": null,
                    "thumbnail5": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "iPhone XMAS",
        "category": "High-Tech",
        "productId": "aDPXF7Xq",
        "details": {
            "rating": "4",
            "stocks": "20",
            "price": "800000",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tags1": "Apple",
                    "tags2": null,
                    "tags3": null
                }
            ],
            "brand": "Apple",
            "description": "Iphone X",
            "picture": [
                {
                    "picture1": "photo1",
                    "picture2": null,
                    "picture3": null,
                    "picture4": null,
                    "picture5": null
                }
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "thumbnail1": "thumbails 1",
                    "thumbnail2": null,
                    "thumbnail3": null,
                    "thumbnail4": null,
                    "thumbnail5": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "iPhone XR",
        "category": "High-Tech",
        "productId": "cjjVqOBk",
        "details": {
            "rating": "2",
            "stocks": "20",
            "price": "800000",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tags1": "Apple",
                    "tags2": null,
                    "tags3": null
                }
            ],
            "brand": "Apple",
            "description": "Iphone X",
            "picture": [
                {
                    "picture1": "photo1",
                    "picture2": null,
                    "picture3": null,
                    "picture4": null,
                    "picture5": null
                }
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "thumbnail1": "thumbails 1",
                    "thumbnail2": null,
                    "thumbnail3": null,
                    "thumbnail4": null,
                    "thumbnail5": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And here is the code I set up for filtering

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        final Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(

                        criteria.orOperator(
                                Criteria.where("name").regex(query, "i"),
                                Criteria.where("details.brand").regex(query, "i"),
                                Criteria.where("details.tags.tags1").regex(query, "i"),
                                Criteria.where("details.tags.tags2").regex(query, "i"),
                                Criteria.where("details.tags.tags3").regex(query, "i")

                        ).andOperator(
                                Criteria.where("details.brand").in(brand),
                                Criteria.where("details.rating").in(rating)

                        )

                ),
                Aggregation.skip(page * pageable.getPageSize()),
                Aggregation.limit(pageable.getPageSize())

        );
        List<Products> filter = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Product", Products.class).getMappedResults();
        return new PageImpl<Products>(filter, pageable, filter.size());
    }
```

But the filtering does not work correctly, I explain to you

If I want to have the brands, I must also put the rating which corresponds to the brands

And if I want to have the ratings, I must also put the brands that correspond to the ratings

So you see my problem a bit, vice versa

Now, what I want is to have all the brands that have a rating of 5 for example

Or again all the ratings of all the products that have a rating of 4

I really hope you see what I mean all your help is welcome thank you

Comment: where are the variables `query`, `brand`, and `rating` in the `Aggregation.match` getting their values?

Comment: Do you want to get both brand and rating but filter may on either brand or rating ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: @sultania23 Hello what I want is when I filter a brand I want to have all the ratings available on this brand

Comment: @Joe Hello  here's the code [link](https://ibb.co/BThZ082)